# Error System.NotSupportedException : The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

After data saved which is it went through the string it shows an error The given path format is not supported, Did I do something wrong or I placed the `url` converter codes in the wrong place?

```
try
{
     connect.Open();
     OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
     command.Connection = connect;
     command.CommandText = string.Format("insert into RegisterItem([Name], [Url],[Description], [Price]) values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", 
                                      ItemName.Text, 
                                      ItemUrl.Text, 
                                      ItemDescription.Text, 
                                      ItemPrice.Text);

     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");

     txtID1.Text = txtUsername.Text;
     txtName1.Text = ItemName.Text;
     txtDescription1.Text = ItemDescription.Text;
     txtPrice1.Text = ItemPrice.Text;
     ItemName.Text = "";
     ItemDescription.Text = "";
     ItemPrice.Text = "";
     string str = ItemUrl.Text;
     pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
     string str1 = textBox1.Text;
     Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
     pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
}
finally
{
     if (Connect != null) { connect.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: What's in `ItemUrl`? We can't see your computer :)

Comment: It's a textbox ,That you type url and the picture will be loaded on pictureBox1

Comment: But what is the `ItemUrl.Text` value that causes the exception?

Comment: What do you mean? The exception is cause of ItemUrl.Text ? It works tho just that theres the exception out after the " data saved "

Answer (score 1):

It is the

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
```

that causes the problem. Image can not be loaded from Url, but must be file path.

In order to load image from url you have to

```
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg");
        Image img;
        using (var rs = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            img = Image.FromStream(rs);
        }
```

Actually, you can completely omit

```
 Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
 pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

This part of code exactly does all the job

```
 pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
```

Image.FromFile loads only from disk file, but setting ImageLocation can load from url and at the same time draws and image to the canvas

Comment: Really? Cause before i changed other codes , this works as fine , It loads while puting a direct link url

Comment: Is there anyway for this method to work? Loaded by direct link after converted from websites like postimage.org

Comment: Is there any way to load image instantly after a file path link like C:\Users\Teronkee\Pictures\98b288f6-e204-40fe-a4f3-cb83a21f4be3.jpg is typed in? cant seem to archive it , The method i used only supports with the browse function